# What libraries are available for solving problems at the college physics level?

Tags: symbolic-computation

Are there any libraries available for solving problems at the level of college physics?

In particular, I'm interested in libraries for general purpose programming languages that can calculate results both numerically *and* symbolically.

Libraries which could be used for implementing something like this are SymPy (Python), GiNaC (C++), or SymbolicC++ (C++).

I'm asking this question because I've started cooking up a [C# library for symbolic computation](https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism) and have used it to solve a few projectile motion problems, but would like to review other work out there.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism/blob/master/PSE%205E%20Example%204.5%20Thats%20Quite%20An%20Arm/Program.cs) of a program which solves such a problem.

Here's what the program outputs when run:

[image: photo]

Any pointers or suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: dharmatech, welcome to SciComp! Your question looks a little broad to me. There are many libraries available that set up math problems. There are also many libraries that will provide functions useful to calculate quantities for various application areas. Examples would be libraries like [OpenFOAM](http://www.openfoam.com/) for fluid mechanics, and [Cantera](https://code.google.com/p/cantera/) for combustion chemistry. Are you looking for applications libraries that overlap with college physics (mechanics, electricity & magnetism), or math libraries you can adapt for your needs?

Comment: Hi @GeoffOxberry. I'm interested in math libraries which can be adapted to (for example) problems at the college physics and engineering level. But if there are particular libraries which support things like projectile motion, I'd be interested in reviewing those as well.

Comment: I suggest refining further what you would like in a math library. As it stands right now, I can recommend libraries that implement basic matrix-vector operations, solve linear equations, integrate ordinary differential equations, solve partial differential equations, and frameworks that do most (or all) of the above. Few of them (that I know of, if any) interoperate with symbolic computation smoothly, but all will work with standard double precision arithmetic, and some will even work in extended (or arbitrary) precision.

Comment: sympy.physics sounds great.